# Почему возникает ошибка "invalid syntax"?

Tags: python, sqlite

Пишу код на Python и SQLite, и возникает ошибка `invalid syntax`. Можно ли её как-то исправить?

```
def dell(self):
    for y in range(1, self.kol + 1):
        exec('if self.checkBox_{}.isChecked():\n\t'.format(y) +\
             'self.checkBox_{}.setCheckState(False)\n\t'.format(y) +\
             'self.gridLayout_1.removeWidget(' + 'self.widget_{})'.format(y) +\
             'or self.gridLayout_2.removeWidget(' + 'self.widget_{})\n\t'.format(y) + \

             'cur = self.con.cursor()\n\t' + \
             'sql = """DELETE FROM Задачи WHERE Название = ?"""\n\t' +\
             'rezult = cur.execute(sql, ("self.widget_{}".format(y),)))\n\t' +\

             'self.widget_{}.hide()\n\t'.format(y) + \
             
             'self.kol -= 1\n\t' +\
             'self.kol_1 -= 1')
```

Comment: на какой строке выдает ошибку?

Comment: Ошибка появляется на 10 строке, но написано, что на 15

Comment: Скобки посчитай

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У одна лишния закрывающийся скобки

```
'rezult = cur.execute(sql, ("self.widget_{}".format(y),)))\n\t' +\
```

должно быть

```
'rezult = cur.execute(sql, ("self.widget_{}".format(y),))\n\t' +\
```

Comment: Ошибка пропала, и выяснилось, что функция неправильно работает: она должна скрывать виджет и удалять его из базы данных, но в базе он остается. Я новичок в SQLite и не могу определить причину проблемы, а также ничего не нашел по ней. Можно ли как-то исправить новую ошибку?

Comment: извините, я не разбираюсь в SQLite

Comment: Почему не хватает? Наоборот, одна лишняя.

Comment: извините, я случайно